# Using multithreading in flask to curl many urls

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a program which connects to around 20 websites and get the status code. I have implemented multithreading to do that concurrently. I want to display the same on a dashbord created in flask. I want the page to fetch the status code each time the page refreshes.

```
  @app.route('/')
  def dash():
    return  render_template('index.html', stats=stat)
    #return str(dataMap)

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.url = url
    def run(self):
        print "Polling " + self.url
        # Get lock to synchronize threads
        threadLock.acquire()
        respose = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        stat.append(response.getcode())
        # Free lock to release next thread
        threadLock.release()


if __name__=="__main__":
    stat = []
    threadLock = threading.Lock()
    threads = []
    fob = open('links.txt','r')
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(fob)
    i=1
    for link in dataMap:
        thread = myThread(i, link)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: In my program, it fetches only first time and for every page refresh,it shows only the data fetched initially. I want it to happen on each page refresh.

Comment: Well your only calling the thread in __main__ so it only going to happen once. To have something happen on each refresh it needs to be in the 'dash' function. The second problem is threads, its not good to spawn them in a web request. I would suggest using workers (celery, rq, etc...). The question is do you need the status on every request?

Comment: Yes, I need. Its a dashbord and i need to have the updated data always.

Comment: You may want to look at using [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or having a separate process that polls the servers and updates a flat file or SQLite database (your web process can read that data store and display the data there).

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this to get info from url every time the root page gets refresh.

```
stat = []
threadLock = threading.Lock()
threads = []
fob = open('links.txt','r')
dataMap = yaml.safe_load(fob)
i=1


@app.route('/')
def dash():
    global dataMap
    global threads
    for link in dataMap:
        thread = myThread(i, link)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    return  render_template('index.html', stats=stat)

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.url = url
    def run(self):
        print "Polling " + self.url
        # Get lock to synchronize threads
        global threadLock
        threadLock.acquire()
        respose = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        global stat
        stat.append(response.getcode())
        # Free lock to release next thread
        threadLock.release()


if __name__=="__main__":


    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```